# create running total of non-zero days in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tableA that has two columns, a date column and a value column.  I would like to write a query that would give me a new column "zeroDays" that counts the number of days the value column has been 0 since the last time it was non zero.  can anyone suggests how to do this with a sql query?  it seems like I should be able to do a self join but I'm having trouble with the logic.

tableA:

```
date value
12/1 1
12/2 0
12/3 0
12/4 2
12/5 0
12/6 1
```

tableB:

```
date value zeroDays
12/1 1     0
12/2 0     1
12/3 0     2
12/4 2     3
12/5 0     1
12/6 1     2
```

Comment: Which DBMS and version are you using? SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, ???

Comment: @Nick how about mysql

Comment: Which version 5.x or 8?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql 8.0 then following solution will work. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v8NehN7Pn6bZA3wQfkzJex/2).

```
select
    date,
    value,
    sum(case 
            when n_val in (1, 0) then 1 
            when n_val > 1 then -n_val
        else
            0
        end
       ) over (order by date) as zeroDays
from
(
    select
        *,
        lag(value) over (order by date) as n_val
    from myTable

) val

order by
    date
```

Output:

```
| date | value | zeroDays |
| ---- | ----- | -------- |
| 12/1 | 1     | 0        |
| 12/2 | 0     | 1        |
| 12/3 | 0     | 2        |
| 12/4 | 2     | 3        |
| 12/5 | 0     | 1        |
| 12/6 | 1     | 2        |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative max:

```
select date, value, 
       coalesce(datediff(date,
                         max(case when value <> 0 then date end) over (order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                        ), 0
               )
from t;
```

Note:  This returns `0` until the first non-zero day.  It is not clear what you want in this case.